# Maximum instances of react-window lists in a single page

Tags: reactjs, react-window

How many instances of `FixedSizeList` and `VariableSizeList` that I can have in a single page in react-window?

I'm using react-window to construct a large number of tables in which each table is a react-window's Lists components, I want to know the threshold of those lists that I could have at a time, so that I will try to restrict the count of creating a table.

Thanks in advance !